# Wso2 Identity Server 5.8.0: custom claim attribute in Create User by Scim service

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In my W**SO2 Identy Server (v5.8.0)**, i have added one custom attribute named XXX.
Then, in my web client application, I invoke **/scim2/Users service** to create new user inside IDS.
I successfully create user with correct name, surname, email, phone number and so on, but my custom field is not updated in my user content store.

By other hand, if I update field by data entry and read my user from IDS, I can see my custom attribute XXX correctly.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the following reasons could be caused not to update custom attributes via `scim2/Users` endpoint.

1. Once you add a new local claim and if you want to access/modify its value using SCIM endpoint it should be mapped to scim claim dialect. Follow the steps in extending scim user claims doc in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Extending+SCIM+2.0+User+Schemas
2. If the above step is correctly configured, check the request payload whether the attribute is correctly defined in the payload. If the attribute is not defined in the expected format, WSO2 IS ignores those attributes.

When you trying to update the value via login to the management console and view the user profile through the management console doesn't involve the SCIM APIs. You are directly updating the local claim in the WSO2 local claim dialect. If you have followed the doc mention is [step 1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Extending+SCIM+2.0+User+Schemas) and that attribute has a value, `GET /scim2/Users/{user-id}` should return the attribute in the response.